# ¿fgets no deberia guardar una linea en blanco tambien?

Tags: c

He estado probando la funcion de fgets para un trabajo y a la hora de leer un archivo,no imprime una linea en blanco que es parte del txt. Este es el txt en cuestion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que he usado es el siguiente:

```
    char lines[80];
    in=fopen("fich.txt","r");
    if(in==NULL){
        printf("ERROR");
    }
    else{
        while(fgets(lines,80,in)){
            printf("La linea es: %s",lines);
        }
    }
```

Ejecutando el programa el output imprime todo menos la linea en blanco y quisiera saber el por que.

Comment: Probándolo en mi maquina te puedo asegurar que si imprime la linea en blanco. Queda como: `La linea es:`, y termina la ejecución del programa. No sera que tu editor elimina la ultima linea ya que no contiene nada? Es lo unico que se me puede ocurrir.

Comment: @Pablochaches tambien me pasó y no usé el editor para crear la linea en blanco.

Answer (score 2):

Se supone que sí, revisa las páginas del manual de [fgets](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets). Como nos indican:

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer. A terminating null byte (aq\0aq) is stored after the last character in the buffer.
>
> ---
>
> fgets () lee como máximo un carácter menos que el tamaño de la secuencia y los almacena en el búfer al que apunta s. La **lectura se detiene después de un EOF o una nueva línea**. Si se lee una nueva línea, se almacena en el búfer. **Un byte nulo de terminación (aq \ 0aq) se almacena después del último carácter en el búfer.**

Entonces al leer esa línea al encontrar el salto de línea se detiene la lectura y almacena después un carácter nulo `\0` que como sabrás es un carácter no visible.

En el búfer se vería algo así en cada iteración

1. Línea 1\n\0
2. Línea 2\n\0
3. Línea final.\n\0
4. \n\0

Si no sabes qué es un [null-terminated string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) te recomendaría que ejecutaras este ejemplo

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s", "Hello World\n");
    printf("%s", "He\0llo World\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que pasa es que si la función `fget` se encuentra con un salto de linea y despues un fin de archivo(`EOF`) retorna `FALSE` o `0` causando que el bucle se detenga y enviando un caracter nulo(`\0`) al `char[]` pasado.
Para quitar al editor de texto de la ecuación decidí crear el archivo, para reproducir el problema: solo debes eliminar una linea de la funcion `write_file` esta:

```c
    /*Quita esta linea para ver el ploblema:*/fprintf(file,"  
   ");/**/
```

Aqui está el código completo:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINE 4
//Tu funcion con tu codigo
short read_file(const char* FILE_NAME){
    char lines[80];
    //Mi modificacion fue que declaré la variable in.
    FILE* in=fopen(FILE_NAME,"r");
    
    //Mi modificacion porque al agregarle return no necesitamos el else porque la funcion terminará.
    if(in==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    
    //Mi modificacion para agregar un indice use el bucle for.
    for ( int i=0; fgets(lines,80,in); i++ ){
        printf("La linea %d es: %s",i,lines);
    }
    return 0;
}
//Como este servidor no puedo crear archivos con un editor de texto hago estó:
short write_file(const char* FILE_NAME){
    FILE* file=fopen(FILE_NAME,"w");
    if(file==NULL){
        return -1;
    }
    for ( int i=0; i<MAX_LINE-1; i++ ){
        fprintf(file,"Linea %d\n",i);
    }
    fprintf(file,"Linea final\n");//Al poner \n dejo una linea en blanco.
    /*Quita esta linea para ver el ploblema:*/fprintf(file,"  
   ");/**/
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
//Modifiqué el codigo para que cree y eliminé el archivo al final.
int main() {
    const char* FILE_NAME="fich.txt";
    while ( read_file(FILE_NAME) ){
        //Si no existe el archivo lo creamos para el ejemplo.;)
        if (write_file(FILE_NAME)){//Si en el servidor ocurre un error al crear el archivo terminamos el programa con -1;
            return -1;
        }
    }
    remove(FILE_NAME);
    return 0;
}
```

La solucion fué agregarle espacios al la ultima linea:

```
fprintf(file,"    ");
```

> Nota: En teoria con solo un espacio basta.

### Enlaces:

- [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbattAEH33VwwOAclxLAf6EOK4EEoKATtQ2kKhKWG9GskTVrvOauWkhHxMH/vcT8h/1Z1dSbGdS1thIWt3LmfPOSO5n0u5Wu2QlqpKEY5Ll5IZzN92tpYUzfxaZyfFjDTC9OTL5eTs/BTedJLkUwVZpSUZDZJvV/Ejpdx0yrmxDiyK9DIjhRHvlg7kXNgevD@bnF6en0xP47sO8OVXQXHt8uvh8NsorCXJlKDgWhlJEepnFcI13ylKJezDT1AClsKSmCkE0oOQ5kv3@G2cmQXq6LFTv2u7cV35lfILY311oUDkFnNhuapFV1kN2oBGiSU5UZgSUPGvxDaDYbQUOLQFaQb3o0ZDWcRQxuefJ5PmqP5qqu4f1Hju/4pKWNECgkrzyVKSCBW3ZxizSjLKzNi6Hf@BiEMc0Hg4gixHV0aB1/7hsE86HgHt7cEGlIXl6CzqTkTgX8BuClgewW7Z7VM/pMabKBvow1HnnsV/ZwrD4Q6hRLuklNszVYsKUwOSpbcgrJzTkjnz5mD4mJLjKHaWw1tnYC7yUOHh11HjmBtLDv9tmVpnH/Zc6ZtWaaY/RPyXAE/Io@PW5xz2lLas4c1X73cnDXMXmknbouulOJ4hoTg0HiXJiWITabRwoZmTK8MUtUKghpkSWppa2qT3oWL7ea7aiGCNJSezERbK8BQU4qiXbPf0ub5Vr5fUiKQyJYbNBum2pNNgvuuKx4vL1rNcd/JWZ1ERvvMOsc3rkEZhPzfhZIOOp7AQpKMYmvF@Scdxlz0@H7hb161x3MwZEyuw/mSsNd/kPkk@krcZ3pJ33gYEVbvOj2hA7Of0CgvmZjCKH/Mpg2jDZOsm8V0ozcRz4qOhjaysxeBda/mdz1lbe6NxM/bNt2FhTW5FIYLnW4@9Yr21Vdr5KsxyE9QzjVar3zJTIi9X@/xtHsuDgz8)
- [Para mas información visita está respuesta que ayudó a mejorar la mia.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/495093/205933)

Comment: Como recomendación siempre coloca el código en Stack Overflow es. Pues las respuestas con enlaces externos luego son rechazadas pues el enlace puede caerse (dan de baja el lugar, eliminas el snippet o situaciones parecidas) y la respuesta deja de ser válida.